# Is the Star of Bethlehem mentioned in Hindu scripture?

Tags: scripture, astrology, other-religions, christianity, astronomy

I was watching a BBC program *[The Real Star of Bethlehem: A Christmas Special](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b06t3wst)* recently that tried to solve the mystery surrounding the [Star of Bethlehem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_Bethlehem). The show concluded the "star" was most likely a comet from among six plausible candidates:

1. A Nova
2. A Supernova
3. The rising of a star
4. A rare alignment of Sun or another star and the two planets Jupiter and Saturn (triple conjunction) around 7 BC.
5. Comet
6. Meteor

Considering the Hindu scriptures are much older than Jesus Christ, is there any evidence of this "star" in Hindu scriptures (assuming it was visible from the Indian subcontinent)?

---

**EDIT**:

*How could something much older have evidence of an astronomical event that occurs in the future?*

To be clear, I did not mean prophecies about the star. I'm only talking about the astronomical phenomenon popularly known as Star of Bethlehem or the Christmas Star. If any sightings of this star were recorded in Hindu scripture either during or after the event.

Comment: "...the Hindu scriptures are much older than..." How could something much older have evidence of an astronomical event that occurs in the future???? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda same way how Ramakrishna and adi sankara incarnations have been mentioned.

Comment: Indian systen does recognise comet.and meteorites

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda "How could something much older have evidence of an astronomical event that occurs in the future?" - To be clear, I did not mean prophecies about the star. I'm only talking about the astronomical phenomenon popularly known as Star of Bethlehem or the Christmas Star. If any sighting of the star was recorded in Hindu scripture.

Comment: But Hindu scriptures are generally older than the time of Jesus, so they wouldn't mention it.  It's possible that some Hindu philosophers or other writers might have mentioned it in their works.  But to figure it out, you might want to stick to a specific theory of what the star of Bethlehem was, for instance a comet, and then ask if there were reports of a comet.  In any case, this may be a better question for History.SE rather than Hinduism.SE - you could ask whether the star of Bethlehem was seen by anyone in India.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "may be a better question for History.SE rather than Hinduism.SE" - agree, but that doesn't it make it off-topic for this site! So this need to be re-opened.